# ¿Por qué mi variable "var1" no se considera numérica? El resultado cuando doy click al botón es NaN

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar y encontré este ejercicio donde se pide para hacer un conversor de moneda pero me dice que la var1 no es número.

```
 <input type="text" id="numero"><br>
<input type="button" value="convertir euro a peso" onclick="function moneda();">
<script>
    

    function moneda() {
        var1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero"));
        var resultado = var1 * 4000;
        console.log(resultado)
    }
    moneda();
</script>
```

Comment: cambia `document.getElementById("numero")` por `document.getElementById("numero").value`. Quita también la palabra `funtion` de `onclick` y quita también la llamada `moneda();` del script.

Comment: Gracias, con estas correcciones funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estás obteniendo en ningún momento el valor del `input`, por eso el resultado es `NaN` (que significa `*Not a Number*`). Además, no llames a `moneda()` en tu códio Javascript, porque su llamada debe ocurrir en el evento onclick.

Así debería funcionar:

```js
function moneda() {
  var1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value);
  var resultado = var1 * 4000;
  console.log(resultado)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero"><br>
<input type="button" value="convertir euro a peso" onclick="moneda();">
```

Aunque observo algunas malas prácticas en tu código:

- Deberías evitar la funciones *in line*, es mejor trabajar con escucha de eventos (para este caso puedes escuchar los clicks del botón).
- Es recomendable guardar referencias a los ids de los elementos, por si necesitas utilizarlos en varias partes. Las llamadas al `document` son más costosas. Aunque aquí no re-utilizas el elemento, conviene, por disciplina de código, observar esta práctica.
- Faltan controles, por ejemplo, si el número es negativo, en este caso no debería haber conversión. Lo he resuelto con un ternario, devolviendo `0` en ese caso, cámbialo por lo que necesites según tu contexto.

```js
let theNumber=document.getElementById("numero");
let btnConvert=document.getElementById("btnConvert");
let theResult=document.getElementById("resultado");

btnConvert.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var1 = parseInt(theNumber.value);
  var resultado = var1 > 0 ? var1 * 4000 : 0;
  console.log(resultado);
  theResult.value=resultado;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Valor a convertir"/><br>
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" value="convertir euro a peso" />
<input type="text" id="resultado" placeholder="Resultado convertido" disabled/><br>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, fué muy útil tu ayuda. Mis errores y malas prácticas se deben a que llevo poco más de un mes aprendiendo programación y empecé literalmente desde cero. Voy a tener en cuenta las anotaciones y seguir estudiando.

Comment: @john me alegro de que te haya servido. Es normal cometer errores, sobre todo al principio, pues no se nace sabiendo. Aquí encontrarás siempre alguien que te ayude a resolver los problemas y que, cuando sea preciso, te indicará otros tipos de problemas que puedan haber en el código. Saludos.

Comment: Una curiosidad, cómo hacer para que el resultado de la conversión se escriba dentro de un input type="text" ?

Comment: @john, revisa el último fragmento editado. Basta con agregar tu `input` luego lo alcanzas por su `id` y cambias su `value` dentro de la función de escucha.